# Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings - i don't find the doubled Entry

Tags: java, maven, logging, slf4j

I get this WARNING by Maven build:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.16.0.20200610-1735/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/home/david/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.18.0_1473617060_linux_gtk_x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/5/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.16.0.20200610-1735/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/home/david/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.18.0_1473617060_linux_gtk_x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/5/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
```

My pom.xml contains:

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.brunocvcunha.instagram4j/instagram4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.brunocvcunha.instagram4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>instagram4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/testing/junit-5-tutorial-running-unit-tests-with-maven/ -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-swing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
            <version>11-ea+24</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/testing/junit-5-tutorial-running-unit-tests-with-maven/ -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                    <compilerArgs>--enable-preview</compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>runner.JavaFXrunner</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

And 'mvn dependency:tree' show me this:

```
[INFO] +- org.brunocvcunha.instagram4j:instagram4j:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.brunocvcunha.inutils4j:inutils4j:jar:0.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.10.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bytedeco:javacv:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.bytedeco:javacpp:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:jar:3.1.0-1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg:jar:3.2.1-1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flycapture:jar:2.9.3.43-1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libdc1394:jar:2.2.4-1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libfreenect:jar:0.5.3-1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libfreenect2:jar:0.2.0-1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:librealsense:jar:1.9.6-1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:videoinput:jar:0.200-1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:artoolkitplus:jar:2.3.1-1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flandmark:jar:1.07-1.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.bytedeco:javacv-platform:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv-platform:jar:3.1.0-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:jar:android-arm:3.1.0-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:jar:android-x86:3.1.0-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:jar:linux-x86:3.1.0-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:jar:linux-x86_64:3.1.0-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:jar:linux-armhf:3.1.0-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:jar:linux-ppc64le:3.1.0-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:jar:macosx-x86_64:3.1.0-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:jar:windows-x86:3.1.0-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:jar:windows-x86_64:3.1.0-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg-platform:jar:3.2.1-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg:jar:android-arm:3.2.1-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg:jar:android-x86:3.2.1-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg:jar:linux-x86:3.2.1-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg:jar:linux-x86_64:3.2.1-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg:jar:linux-armhf:3.2.1-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg:jar:linux-ppc64le:3.2.1-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg:jar:macosx-x86_64:3.2.1-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg:jar:windows-x86:3.2.1-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg:jar:windows-x86_64:3.2.1-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flycapture-platform:jar:2.9.3.43-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flycapture:jar:linux-x86:2.9.3.43-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flycapture:jar:linux-x86_64:2.9.3.43-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flycapture:jar:linux-armhf:2.9.3.43-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flycapture:jar:windows-x86:2.9.3.43-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flycapture:jar:windows-x86_64:2.9.3.43-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libdc1394-platform:jar:2.2.4-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libdc1394:jar:linux-x86:2.2.4-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libdc1394:jar:linux-x86_64:2.2.4-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libdc1394:jar:linux-armhf:2.2.4-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libdc1394:jar:linux-ppc64le:2.2.4-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libdc1394:jar:macosx-x86_64:2.2.4-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libdc1394:jar:windows-x86:2.2.4-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libdc1394:jar:windows-x86_64:2.2.4-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libfreenect-platform:jar:0.5.3-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libfreenect:jar:linux-x86:0.5.3-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libfreenect:jar:linux-x86_64:0.5.3-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libfreenect:jar:linux-armhf:0.5.3-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libfreenect:jar:linux-ppc64le:0.5.3-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libfreenect:jar:macosx-x86_64:0.5.3-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libfreenect:jar:windows-x86:0.5.3-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libfreenect:jar:windows-x86_64:0.5.3-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libfreenect2-platform:jar:0.2.0-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libfreenect2:jar:linux-x86:0.2.0-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libfreenect2:jar:linux-x86_64:0.2.0-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:librealsense-platform:jar:1.9.6-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:librealsense:jar:linux-x86:1.9.6-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:librealsense:jar:linux-x86_64:1.9.6-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:videoinput-platform:jar:0.200-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:videoinput:jar:windows-x86:0.200-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:videoinput:jar:windows-x86_64:0.200-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:artoolkitplus-platform:jar:2.3.1-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:artoolkitplus:jar:android-arm:2.3.1-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:artoolkitplus:jar:android-x86:2.3.1-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:artoolkitplus:jar:linux-x86:2.3.1-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:artoolkitplus:jar:linux-x86_64:2.3.1-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:artoolkitplus:jar:linux-armhf:2.3.1-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:artoolkitplus:jar:linux-ppc64le:2.3.1-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:artoolkitplus:jar:macosx-x86_64:2.3.1-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:artoolkitplus:jar:windows-x86:2.3.1-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:artoolkitplus:jar:windows-x86_64:2.3.1-1.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flandmark-platform:jar:1.07-1.3:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flandmark:jar:android-arm:1.07-1.3:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flandmark:jar:android-x86:1.07-1.3:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flandmark:jar:linux-x86:1.07-1.3:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flandmark:jar:linux-x86_64:1.07-1.3:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flandmark:jar:linux-armhf:1.07-1.3:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flandmark:jar:linux-ppc64le:1.07-1.3:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flandmark:jar:macosx-x86_64:1.07-1.3:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flandmark:jar:windows-x86:1.07-1.3:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flandmark:jar:windows-x86_64:1.07-1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.7.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.7.0:test
[INFO] +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.7.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.7.0:test
[INFO] +- org.openjfx:javafx-controls:jar:11.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.openjfx:javafx-controls:jar:linux:11.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.openjfx:javafx-swing:jar:11-ea+24:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.openjfx:javafx-swing:jar:linux:11-ea+24:compile
[INFO] \- org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:jar:11:compile
[INFO]    +- org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:jar:linux:11:compile
[INFO]    \- org.openjfx:javafx-base:jar:11:compile
[INFO]       \- org.openjfx:javafx-base:jar:linux:11:compile
```

I know that I can 'exclude' dependencys in the pom dependency entries. But witch one I must exclude to solve the problem?

I think it give a simple soultion. But I have not that much expierience ...
I would be very happy to get a answer with a little explanation, and not only the soulution.

Comment: ("(still?) Open Ellipse bug", "workaround: Use standalone maven, not embedded(?)")

Comment: Yes, thanks!
To install Maven separately solve the problem. ;-)